# win_find - does not enter the folder IIS logs

Tags: ansible

```
tasks:
    - name: Find older logs file
      win_find:
        paths: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\
        recurse: yes
      register: file_results

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ file_results.files }}"
```

In the LogFiles folder there are the following subfolders where the logs are located:

- test
- W3SVC990866148
- W3SVC1150242952

Log files are inside these folders. Ansible enters the test folder, but suddenly it does not. Why? Administrator rights for the UZ under which is ansible.

The test folder was created manually. If paths: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC990866148\ - Then he sees all the files.

```
[WARNING]: win_find failed to check some files, these files were ignored and

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: /tmp/awx_2383_2n4lsy56/project/clear_iis_log.yml:12
ok: [dtc-srv-sp15] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            ...
            "path": "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\test\\u_ex210112.log",
            "size": 1579
        },
        {
            ...
            "path": "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\test\\u_ex210114.log",
            "size": 644
        },
        {
            ...
            "path": "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\test\\u_ex210119.log",
            "size": 1486
        }
    ]
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
name_host               : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I try to do this:
---
- name: Clear IIS Logs
hosts: all
become_method: runas

```
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: password

  tasks:
    - name: Find older logs file
      win_find:
        paths: c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\
        recurse: yes
        use_patterns: yes
      register: file_results
      become: yes
      become_user: user
```

### Tried the same way

```
- name: Clear IIS Logs
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Find older logs file
      win_find:
        paths: c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\
        recurse: yes
        use_patterns: yes
      register: file_results
      vars:
        ansible_become: yes
        ansible_become_method: runas
        ansible_become_user: user
        ansible_become_password: password
        ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
```

Doesn't go into this folder anyway(

Comment: `these files were ignored and....` => you truncated the warning. You might also get more info running your playbook with `-vvv`. Anyway you need to find out why what is going on and give more debugging details. Meanwhile, this really looks like a permission problem.

Comment: I booted via RDP to this host under the UZ from which Ansible is connected and went through the path in the explorer to this folder. Enters the folder only by confirming UAC. How do I tell Ansible to run as administrator? Launching the playbook with awx. Debug no longer provides the information you need

Comment: `How do I tell Ansible to run as administrator?` => use the `-u` option on command line and/or set `remote_user` at play level and/or set `ansible_user` for that host/group in your inventory and/or connect as your actual user and set-up [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-and-windows)

Comment: Updated 1 post adding more ways, but they also don't work (

Comment: Which version of ansible are you running? https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58463